# auto resize guest display grayed out under virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, display, gui, resize

cannot select "auto resize guest display" or Host-G, because it is grayed out; as a result my ubuntu GUI screen running under VirtualBox does not show the whole page.  For example, if I select system settings, then printer, to add a new printer, the page only shows devices and connection.  Cannot see the page fully rendered.  Any ideas on how I can resize the page to render it all?  Many thanks!

Comment: Are [Guest Additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) installed?